# Dynamically assign a function to a variable on condition then use it in loop typescript 2.3.4

Tags: typescript, this, ionic3

I want to avoid evaluating conditions in the loop so I thought about creating a function that returns the correct treatment assigned in a variable then use that variable in the loop.

Basically the idea looks like:

---

```
export class myClass{

ref;

Treatment1(){code}
Treatment2(){code}
Treatment3(){code}

selectTreatment(){
   if(condition1){
      ref = Treatment1()
   else if(condition2){
      ref = Treatment2()
   else (condition3){
      ref = Treatment3()
}

   executeTreatment(){
      setInterval(ref(),300)
   }


}
```

I'm not sure but I think I have a problem with the `this` keyword !

---

I have found a solution like this:

```
export class myClass{

ref:any;

Treatment1(){code}
Treatment2(){code}
Treatment3(){code}

selectTreatment():Function{
   if(condition1){
      return ()=>{Treatment1()};
   else if(condition2){
      return ()=>{Treatment1()};
   else (condition3){
      return ()=>{Treatment1()};
}

   executeTreatment(){
      this.ref=this.selectTreatement();
      setInterval(ref(),300);
   }


}
```

Comment: Not clear.You need to provide more `code` and details.

Comment: I'm new with typescript and the project is private ! just be patient and tell me what is not clear and think you for replying

Comment: If you see the above `code` only then can you give a solution for someone else? You need to show all the relevant `code`.Where you used `this` on above `code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to determine exactly what your issue is since, like Sampath said, you don't show how this class is used.  Specifically how selectTreatement and executeTreatmeant are called.  But, with the code shown there are a few things that you should change.

1. Like you said, there is an issue with the `this` keyword.  All references to `ref` in `executeTreatment` and `selectTreatment` should be prefixed with `this`.
2. By setting `ref = Treatment1()`, you are setting it to the result of `Treatment1` and not to a reference to `Treatment1`.  You then try to invoke `ref` in `executeTreatment`, which is only going to be valid if `TreatmentX` returns a function.  So, you likely want to change your `selectTreatment` assignments to something like `this.ref = this.Treatment1;`